# Debian Cron Job VLC REPEAT how to stop it

Tags: linux, bash, cron, debian

I have a birdcall that plays every day @ 4AM and would like to stop it at noon.

the command I run is `vlc --repeat sound.wav`

I am running this command from my crontab file.  I figured that I could kill the process with another cron job sh script, however the PID changes each time it is launched, so I find that hard to figure out. I thought about just making the call .wav file the entire length that I would want it to play and let vlc play it one time and be done with it.

Any ideas? I was looking for vlc --repeat durations....but not finding anything.

I really think that if I make the wav file 4 or 5 hours long I should be ok. What do you think?

Thank you for reading this.

****EDIT***

I found the `cvlc --play-and-exit` command   that might help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap `vlc --repeat sound.wav` in a script like so:

```
count_secs=$((8 * 60 * 60)) # 8 hrs * 60 min * 60 sec
vlc --repeat sound.wav &
vlc_pid=$$
sleep $count_secs
kill $vlc_pid
```

Comment: `vlc --repeat sound.wav &` puts vlc into the back ground. The `$$` in `vlc_pid=$$` gives the PID of the bash script. Killing that pid wont kill vlc. On the other hand `$!` gives PID of the last program. `vlc_pid=$!`